# Switching Views using EnvironmentObject (Button and Navigation View) not working

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**What do I want to do?**

I build an App in which you can view different lectures. You are suppose to chose a lecture out of a Navigation View then click on Start Lecture and contine reading.

**How is the App build up?**

**Page 0:** MainMenuView - NavigationView that shows 5 Items (Lectures)

```js
//
//  MainMenuView.swift
//  NewCareerFriends
//
//  Created by Tobias Reidl on 20.09.20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Tobias Reidl. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI

struct MainMenuView: View {

    @State private var model = Topic.all()
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    
    var body: some View {
       

        ZStack
        {
        //Background
        Rectangle()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .foregroundColor(Color(.white))
            
        VStack
        {
        //Logo at the Top
        Image("careerfriends_logo_transparent")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .padding()
            .background(Color("card2"))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding()
            .clipped()
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
        //Lectures as a Navigation View
        NavigationView{
        List {

            ForEach(model) { topic in
                
                TopicCell(topic: topic)
        }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Lektionen"))
        }
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .padding()
        .shadow(radius: 10)
            
}
}
}
    // Custom Navigation View Design
    init() {
        // 1.
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
       
        // 2.
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
            .font : UIFont(name:"Arial", size: 28)!]
                
        // 3.
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
            .font : UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 20)!]
    }
}

// Previewer
struct MainMenuView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainMenuView()
    }
}

// Custom Cells for the NavigationView
struct TopicCell: View {
    
    let topic : Topic

    var body: some View {
        // Below is the error message
        return NavigationLink(destination: LectureFullView(topic: topic).environmentObject(ViewRouter())){
            
            HStack{
                Image(topic.Image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 160)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                VStack{
                    Text(topic.Title)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    
                    Text(topic.Text)
                        .lineLimit(7)
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Page 1:** LectureFullView - Shows Quick Item (Lecture) introduction, Button to "Start Lecture"

```js
//
//  LectureFullView.swift
//  NewCareerFriends
//
//  Created by Tobias Reidl on 23.09.20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Tobias Reidl. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI




struct LectureFullView: View {
    
    
    let topic : Topic
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack
        {
        
            ScrollView{
            VStack{
            Image(topic.Image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Text(topic.Title)
                .font(.system(size: 32))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                
            Text(topic.Text)
                .font(.system(size: 17))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                .padding(.leading)
                .padding(.trailing)
                .padding(.bottom)
                }
                
               
                VStack{
                Button(action:
                {
                    self.viewRouter.currentPage = "page2"
                })
                {
                    Text("Lektion starten")
                    .font(.body)
                }
                }
                .padding(.bottom)
            }

        }
    }
}

struct LectureFullView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LectureFullView(topic: Topic.all()[0]).environmentObject(ViewRouter())
    }
}
```

**Page 2:** LevelOneView - Shows Part One of the Lecture

```js
//
//  LevelOneView.swift
//  NewCareerFriends
//
//  Created by Tobias Reidl on 27.09.20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Tobias Reidl. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI

struct LevelOneView: View {

    let topic: Topic
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
         
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    
                Button(action: {
                     //
                 })
                 {
                Text("Zurück")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(.white))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .clipped()
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
                 }
                Text("Teil 1")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(.white))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .clipped()
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
                   
                    Button(action: {
                        self.viewRouter.currentPage = "Page1"
                    })
                    {
                    Text("Weiter")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(.white))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .clipped()
                        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
                    }
                }
                    
                
                Spacer()
                InformationView(topic: topic)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image("BannerWindow1")
                .resizable()
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .scaledToFit()
                .padding()
                .shadow(radius: 10)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LevelOneView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LevelOneView(topic: Topic.all()[0]).environmentObject(ViewRouter())
    }
}

struct InformationView: View {
    
    let topic : Topic
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView
            {
                Text(topic.Information01)
                
                Spacer()

            }
        .padding()
        .background(Color(.white))
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .padding(.leading)
        .padding(.trailing)
        .clipped()
        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
        
    
    }
}
```

**Additional:** LectureMotherView - Controls which view to show

```js
//
//  LectureMotherView.swift
//  NewCareerFriends
//
//  Created by Tobias Reidl on 27.09.20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Tobias Reidl. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI

struct LectureMotherView: View {
    
//    @State var page: String = "page0"
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
           
            if viewRouter.currentPage == "page1"
            {
                LectureFullView(topic: Topic.all()[0])
            }
            else if viewRouter.currentPage == "page2"
            {
                LevelOneView(topic: Topic.all()[0])
            }
            else if viewRouter.currentPage == "page0"
            {
                MainMenuView()
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct LectureMotherView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LectureMotherView().environmentObject(ViewRouter())
    }
}
```

**Additional:** ViewRouter - Keeps track of changes on page 0 to 2

```js
//
//  LectureMotherView.swift
//  NewCareerFriends
//
//  Created by Tobias Reidl on 27.09.20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Tobias Reidl. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI

struct LectureMotherView: View {
    
//    @State var page: String = "page0"
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
           
            if viewRouter.currentPage == "page1"
            {
                LectureFullView(topic: Topic.all()[0])
            }
            else if viewRouter.currentPage == "page2"
            {
                LevelOneView(topic: Topic.all()[0])
            }
            else if viewRouter.currentPage == "page0"
            {
                MainMenuView()
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct LectureMotherView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LectureMotherView().environmentObject(ViewRouter())
    }
}
```

**Additional**: Topic - Stores the data

```js
//
//  TopicModel.swift
//  NewCareerFriends
//
//  Created by Tobias Reidl on 23.09.20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Tobias Reidl. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct  Topic: Identifiable
{
    let id = UUID()
    let Title: String
    let Image: String
    let Text: String
    let Information01: String
    let Question: String
}

extension Topic
{
    static func all() -> [Topic]
    {
        return [
            
            Topic(Title: "Job finden", Image: "Window1", Text: "Nach drei Semestern studieren sucht Tim nach einer Möglichkeit erste, fachliche Berufserfahrung zu sammeln. Hierzu macht er sich auf die Suche nach einem Job den er neben dem Studium ausüben kann. In dieser Lektion lernst du die grundlegenden Information um einen studentischen Job zu finden.",
                Information01: "Die Online Jobbörse ist der bekannteste Ort zum Jobs finden, allerdings gibt es oftmals andere und teilweise sogar effektivere Methoden. Über Bekannte oder Mitstudenten herauszufinden in welchem Unternehmen sie vielleicht sogar aktuell als Student tätig sind gibt dir ggf. die Möglichkeit viel vom Standard Bewerbungsprozess zu überspringen und direkt durch Empfehlung bevorzugt zu werden. Dies ist dann besonders ein Vorteil wenn du bisher noch nicht so viele Erfahrungen hast. Wenn dein Lebenslauf nicht unbedingt Bände spricht macht eine Empfehlung von einem Mitstudenten schon einiges aus, solange er natürlich selbst gute Arbeit leistet. ", Question: "Hallo"),
            
            
            
            Topic(Title: "Bewerben", Image: "Window2", Text: "Nachdem du einen interessanten Job gefunden hast geht es ans bewerben. Doch wie genau bewirbt man sich richtig als Student? Was ist gern gesehen und was verrufen? Sich bewerben ist ein bisschen wie Dating. Du möchtest der anderen Person deinen Wert zeigen, bzw. auf deine Attraktivität als Mitarbeiter aufmerksam machen. Je mehr du mit der anderen Person gemeinsam hast und je eher ihr von euren Werten und Einstellungen zueinander passt, desto wahrscheinlicher findet ihr euch interessant. Das Bewerbungsschreiben und das Vorstellungsgespräch sind sich im Grunde sehr ähnlich. Die folgenden Tipps sind deshalb ebenfalls für ein Vorstellungsgespräch relevant. ", Information01: "Dies ist eine INFO",  Question: "HalloHalli"),
            
            
            
            Topic(Title: "Interviews", Image: "Window3", Text: "„Hallo Tim. Vielen Dank für deine Bewerbung. Wir möchten dich gerne näher kennenlernen und schlagen dir ein persönliches Interview vor. Passt dir nächsten Mittwoch?“ Endlich hat es Tim geschafft zu einem Vorstellungsgespräch eingeladen zu werden. Aber was soll er ohne viel Berufserfahrung erzählen? Eigentlich ist das Vorstellungsgespräch gar nicht so schwierig zu meistern wie viele denken. Auch ohne Berufserfahrung kannst du viele interessante und spannende Dinge erzählen, die dein Gegenüber begeistern und dafür Sorge tragen, dass du den Job bekommst. ", Information01: "Dies ist eine INFO",  Question: "HalloHalli"),
            
            
            
            
            Topic(Title: "Selbstreflexion", Image: "Window4", Text: "Marie ist einige Monate in einem Werkstudenten Job und fragt sich nun, ob sie direkt fest beim Unternehmen einsteigen sollte, oder ob es nochmal sinnvoll wäre ein neuen Praktikum bzw. eine neue Werkstudententätigkeit zu verfolgen. Auf der einen Seite reizt es sie nochmal etwas neues zu machen, auf der anderen Seite hat sie Angst die falsche Entscheidung zu treffen und sich den Weg zurück zu verbauen.", Information01: "Dies ist eine INFO",  Question: "HalloHalli"),
            
            
            
            
            Topic(Title: "Mit Kollegen & Chef interagieren ", Image: "Window5", Text: "Du bist also mittendrin in deinen ersten Arbeitswochen und versucht einen guten Eindruck bei deinen Kollegen zu hinterlassen, was nicht einfach ist. Wie überall ist natürlich auch der erste Eindruck auf der Arbeit zum großen Teil entscheidend dafür, was die Menschen für ein Bild von dir haben. Besonders dein Team und dein Chef werden dies in den ersten Arbeitstagen genau beobachten. Lass uns am Beispiel von „Tim“ herausfinden, welche Verhaltensmuster mit hoher Wahrscheinlichkeit kompetent oder inkompetent von seinen Kollegen gedeutet werden.", Information01: "Dies ist eine INFO", Question: "HalloHalli"),
            
            
            
            
            Topic(Title: "Übernahme / Neuer Job", Image: "Window6", Text: "Stell dir vor du bist nun seit ein paar Monaten bei einem Unternehmen. Das Team ist super und das Unternehmen gefällt dir auch. Du kannst dir gut vorstellen fest anzufangen und möchtest schon vorab alle Weichen so stellen, dass vielleicht sogar dein Chef und deine Kollegen auf dich proaktiv zukommen. Um die Chancen bei einem Unternehmen fest einzusteigen zu steigern musst du zeigen, dass du alle Aufgaben die ein Festangestellter erledigt, ebenfalls kannst. Deine Strategie sollte also sein dir alle nötigen Fähigkeiten anzueignen.  Hast du die Grundlagen erlernt geht es darum ein wertgeschätztes und unersetzbares Teambestandteil zu werden. Dies gilt für den sozialen Umgang mit deinem Team und auch Chef. ", Information01: "Dies ist eine INFO",  Question: "HalloHalli"),
        ]
        
        
    }
}
```

**What is the problem?**

On **Page 1**: When I click the Button "Start Lecture" nothing happens.

**What should happen?**

It should display **Page2**

**Why do I thin that is?**

I read that Navigation View and Environment Object don't get along very well. However I can't tell whats the specific issue.

**Do I get any error message?**

No, everything runs fine

I hope you guys can help me, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same `ViewRouter` instance across the whole app.

In the `TopicCell` view you're creating a **new** instance of `ViewRouter`:

```
return NavigationLink(destination: LectureFullView(topic: topic).environmentObject(ViewRouter())) {
```

so when you modify the *new* instance in the `LectureFullView`, the *original* one will not be affected.

To fix this, you need to pass the same instance that already exists in the environment:

```
struct TopicCell: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter // get EnvironmentObject
    
    let topic : Topic

    var body: some View {
        // pass the existing `viewRouter` to the destination view
        NavigationLink(destination: LectureFullView(topic: topic).environmentObject(viewRouter)) {
        ...
```

Comment: Wow it worked! Thank you so much I really appreciate your answer, you saved my life!!